# How to access raw text of each chapter in user uploaded EPUB file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I am trying to access the raw text of a user uploaded EPUB file.

Tried a few libraries with no luck, most require a local file path to access the files contents it seems and I don't know how to access a temporary file path for it.

I have access to the javascript File object as I'm using React-Dropzone.

Here's the docs on one Epub library that seems perfect if I could get it to read the uploaded file:
https://github.com/julien-c/epub

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to access file contents you have to use the FileReader API, and use reader.readAsBinaryString(file), then just stream it to where you want.

Comment: @n3wb I tried that and can get that data back fine but all of the librarys to parse the data want a file path in order to load the epub and access chapters